# How to access arrays using bracket notation in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 2 using composition api I could use:

```js
setup(props) {
  const vm = getCurrentInstance().proxy
  const selectedFeatures = ref([])
  const selectedGames = ref([])
  const selectedTVChannels = ref([])

  const filtered = computed(() => {
    const filterArray = [
      {selected: "selectedFeatures", dbField: "features"},
      {selected: "selectedGames", dbField: "games"},
      {selected: "selectedTVChannels", dbField: "tvChannels"}
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < filterArray.length; i++) {
      if (vm[filterArray[i].selected].length > 0) {
        temp = temp.filter(item => {
          if (item.hasOwnProperty(filterArray[i].dbField)) {
            let t = 0
            for (let j = 0; j < vm[filterArray[i].selected].length; j++) {
              for (let k = 0; k < item[filterArray[i].dbField].length; k++) {
                if (item[filterArray[i].dbField][k] === vm[filterArray[i].selected][j]) t++
              }
            }
            if (t === vm[filterArray[i].selected].length) return true
          }
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

I am trying to get this code to work inside `<script setup>` in Nuxt 3. But I can not work out a way to access arrays by bracket notation in this configuration. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to find `refs` values through `vm` but they're really empty.

I wonder what stops you from using

```js
const arrays = reactive({
  selectedFeatures: [],
  selectedGames:[], 
  selectedTVChannels:[],
})
```

so you could access them with bracket notation

```js
arrays[filterArray[i].selected]
```